# Bash, Linux, Need to remove lines from one file based on matching content from another file

Tags: linux, bash, grep

There are many examples on how to remove lines in one file when that same line exists in another file.  I have read through them and they all remove if the full line matches.  Examples like: `grep -vxF -f file1 file2`

What I have is slightly different.  I have a list of URLs from my websites and my clients websites.  I want to remove lines from that file when the domain matches a domain in another file.

So the first file might look like:

```
http://www.site1.com/some/path
http://www.site2.com/some/path
http://www.site3.com/some/path
http://www.site4.com/some/path
```

The second file could be:

```
site2.com
www.site4.com
```

I would like the output to be:

```
http://www.site1.com/some/path
http://www.site3.com/some/path
```

Answer (score 2):

You have too many `grep` flags. Specifically: `-x` will keep you from getting your desired results.

Assuming that *file1* has the patterns, and *file2* has the URLs, just use:

```
grep -v -f file1 file2
```

The `-x` flag will keep you from getting the results that you want: using `-x` means: match only against the entire line, i.e. only match a line if the line is exactly, e.g. *site2.com*.

From the `man grep`:

> -x, --line-regexp
>
> Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some corner cases this doesn't handle, but you can simply use the `-v` and `-f` options of `grep`:

```
grep -f file2.txt -v file1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work (untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

open my $fh, "<$ARGV[1]" || die $!;

my $filter=join "|", <$fh>;

close $fh;

open $fh, "<$ARGV[0]" || die $!;

print grep !m{^http://[^/]*($filter)/}x, <$fh>;

close $fh;
```