# Extract strings in a text file using grep

Tags: string, shell, grep, string-matching

I have file.txt with names one per line as shown below:

```
ABCB8
ABCC12
ABCC3
ABCC4
AHR
ALDH4A1
ALDH5A1
....
```

I want to grep each of these from an input.txt file.

Manually i do this one at a time as

```
grep "ABCB8" input.txt > output.txt
```

Could someone help to automatically grep all the strings in file.txt from input.txt and write it to output.txt.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for line in `cat text.txt`; do grep $line input.txt >> output.txt; done
```

Contents of `text.txt`:

```
ABCB8
ABCC12
ABCC3
ABCC4
AHR
ALDH4A1
ALDH5A1
```

**Edit**:

A safer solution with while read:

```
cat text.txt | while read line; do grep "$line" input.txt >> output.txt; done
```

**Edit 2**:

Sample `text.txt`:

```
ABCB8
ABCB8XY
ABCC12
```

Sample `input.txt`:

```
You were hired to do a job; we expect you to do it.
You were hired because ABCB8 you kick ass;
we expect you to kick ass.
ABCB8XY You were hired because you can commit to a rational deadline and meet it;
ABCC12 we'll expect you to do that too.
You're not someone who needs a middle manager tracking your mouse clicks
```

If You don't care about the order of lines, the quick workaround would be to pipe the solution through a `sort | uniq`:

```
cat text.txt | while read line; do grep "$line" input.txt >> output.txt; done; cat output.txt | sort | uniq > output2.txt
```

The result is then in `output.txt`.

**Edit 3**:

```
 cat text.txt | while read line; do grep "\<${line}\>" input.txt >> output.txt; done
```

Is that fine?

Comment: `for` loop is not the right tool for this, please read [Why you don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Plus `grep` is already looping on the input file.

Comment: @EdouardLopez: I know, but it doesn't matter in this simple example. Any way I never have had any trobles using `while read`.

Comment: You spread bad practices, you `while/for` is useless, you are trying to emulate the behavior or `grep` (looping each line of a file) to pass them to… `grep`.

Comment: Please state your approach more clearly: create a 2nd file containing the list of pattern, use it as input for the `grep`. This is also awkward as the file you base your approach upon is the result @user1779730 is looking for. Hence your solution is based on itself (infinite loop :S)

Comment: @EdouardLopez: I thought the strings to grep are the ones in the `text.txt`. And as I understood the OP -- it is asking for a loop.

Comment: @Adobe Both solutions using while and for loop gives empty output.

Comment: @user1779730: I don't see the reason. I could try and see it myself, if You'd post a sample `input.txt`

Comment: @Adobe Hi it is working fine now. But, i have another issue. For example if we grep 'ABCB8', it gives the output if there is 'ABCB8XY'. I need to grep if and only if it matches the exact string 'ABCB8'.

Comment: @user1779730: Are You free in time? I'd get back to Your problem in some 10-20 hours?

Comment: To the downvoters: I know it is a useless use of cat and loop, and the whole thing might be done in one grep pipe. BUT -- in most cases speed is not an issue, while knowing 100,000 options of coreutils is an issue if You have other things You responsible for. So why not just program the thing at hand?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-f` flag as described in [Bash, Linux, Need to remove lines from one file based on matching content from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12011126/802365)

```
grep -o -f file.txt input.txt > output.txt
```

### Flag

- `-f FILE`, `--file=FILE`:

> Obtain patterns from FILE, one  per  line.   The  empty  file 
>   contains  zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  (-f is
>   specified by POSIX.)

- `-o`, `--only-matching`:

> Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with 
>   each  such part on a separate output line.

Comment: I got the `input.txt` file with highlighted lines from `file.txt`

Comment: Try without the `> output.txt`. Note that `file.txt` contains le list of patterns, `input.txt` is the file to look into.