# extract data from text file with linux

Tags: linux

I have file and I need to extract some data. the problem I'm facing is some line not almost the same with other lines. here is the example:

```
 action=accept trandisp=noop srcip=1.1.1.1 dstip=2.2.2.2 service=PING proto=1 duration=61 
 action=accept trandisp=noop srcip=1.1.1.1 dstip=3.3.3.3 dstport=80 service=http proto=1 duration=61
```

I want to get the destination IP with service in the first row, and the 
destination IP with dstport and service in the second line.

I'm new in linux and I tried it with grep and cut but it didn't work for me.
please help me with the explanation of your answer.

Comment: May we what you've tried? Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291557/extract-strings-in-a-text-file-using-grep) might be helpful

Comment: Good case for `gawk` (or perhaps `perl`), or maybe `sed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this one?
`grep -o -P "dstip=[0-9.]+ (dstport=[0-9]+)? service=\w+ (dstport=[0-9]+)?" your-file`

Explanation:

```
-o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN
-P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
```

Of course, key-value order matters.

Comment: This is a perl regex. The `+` means one or more and is applied to `[0-9.]`. The `?` means none or one and is applied to `(dstport=[0-9]+ service=\w+)`.

Comment: Wow that's work good, but the + what is it for and also (dstport=[0-9]+ service=\w+)?... the ().. \w+...and the question mark... one more thing sometimes service come before dstport. is there any work around for that... thank you

Comment: the grep if the line doesn't have [dstport=xx]  as shown in first line of the file I sent it will only print the [dstip] and ignore [service=PING]. also when I send the output to a file, it doesn't print new lines.

Comment: Edited. I didn't try it but that should do the trick. I think the new lines problem is unrelated to the original question.